# segmentation fault - strange debug statements

Tags: c++, singleton, segmentation-fault, stack-trace

I'm trying to build my own exception class with function tracing (I want to know the file and line numbers of all functions called up to an exception, and also the amount of times them functions have been called in total)

The function tracing seemed to work whilst building it, but then when trying to use it properly I have been besieged by segmentation faults. I've tracked some of them down (silly errors like forgetting to return anything or dropping ampersands) but this one is killing me - what's more I cannot yet figure out how I am getting the debugging statements I'm seeing.

I expect my code needs a lot of improvement (and I'd be grateful for any advice or scathing comments about what I absolutely shouldn't be doing) but can anyone help me figure out what's going one here. I've tried to exploit my FunctionTrace class, and thrown cout statements where I think they're useful but I'm getting nowhere.

I include a stripped out int main(), FunctionTrace.{c,h}pp, MathsException.hpp (no .cpp yet), and the output from gdb (still learning to use this)

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "FunctionTrace.hpp"
#include "MathsException.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    LOG_FUNC_CALL
    try
    {
        std::string test = "";
        MathsException oExc(test);
        throw oExc;
    }
    catch(MathsException& iException)
    {
        iException.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

FunctionTrace.cpp

```
#include "FunctionTrace.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

static int countDebugStatic = 0; //TODO delete me!

int& FunctionCallDetails::getLine(){return lineNumber;}

const char* FunctionCallDetails::getFile(){return file;}

int& FunctionCallDetails::getNoOfTimesCalled(){return noOfTimesCalled;}

FunctionTrace::FunctionTrace(const int iLineNumber, const char* iFile)
{
    FunctionTraceManager& fnTraceMgr = FunctionTraceManager::getInstance();

    int oTimesCalled = ++fnTraceMgr.getAllTimesCalled()[std::make_pair(iLineNumber, iFile)];
    fnTraceMgr.getAllFunctionCalls().push_back(FunctionCallDetails(iLineNumber, iFile, oTimesCalled));
}

std::vector<std::string>& FunctionTraceManager::gatherFunctionCalls()
{
    FunctionTraceManager& fnTraceMgr = FunctionTraceManager::getInstance();
    std::vector<FunctionCallDetails>::iterator fnCallsIter =  fnTraceMgr.getAllFunctionCalls().begin();
    std::vector<std::string> oFnDetails;
    for(; fnCallsIter != fnTraceMgr.getAllFunctionCalls().end(); ++fnCallsIter)
    {
        countDebugStatic++;
        std::cout << "count: " << countDebugStatic << "\n";
        std::string fnDetail = "Function at line: ";
        char lineCalled[11]; //I'd never live long enough to generate this many lines of code in one file
        snprintf(lineCalled, 10, "%d", fnCallsIter->getLine());
        fnDetail += lineCalled;
        fnDetail += ", in file: ";
        fnDetail += fnCallsIter->getFile();
        fnDetail += " called: ";
        char noOfTimesCalled[11]; //log(2^32)/log(10) = 9.~~ (need a null char) 
        snprintf(noOfTimesCalled, 10, "%d", fnCallsIter->getNoOfTimesCalled());
        fnDetail += noOfTimesCalled;
        fnDetail += " times.";
        oFnDetails.push_back(fnDetail);
        std::cout << "fnDetail: " << fnDetail << "\n";
    }
    if(oFnDetails.size() > 0)
    {
        return oFnDetails;
    }
    else
    {
        oFnDetails.push_back("");
        return oFnDetails;
    }
}


FunctionTrace::~FunctionTrace()
{
    FunctionTraceManager& fnTraceMgr = FunctionTraceManager::getInstance();
    fnTraceMgr.getAllFunctionCalls().pop_back();
}
```

FunctionTrace.hpp

```
#ifndef FUNCTION_TRACE_HPP
#define FUNCTION_TRACE_HPP

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

class FunctionCallDetails
{
    int lineNumber;
    const char* file;
    int noOfTimesCalled;
    public:
        FunctionCallDetails(const int iLineNumber, const char* iFile, int iTimesCalled): lineNumber(iLineNumber), file(iFile), noOfTimesCalled(iTimesCalled){};
        int& getLine();
        const char* getFile();
        int& getNoOfTimesCalled();
};

class FunctionTraceManager
{
    //singleton
    std::vector<FunctionCallDetails> functionCalls;
    std::map<std::pair<const int,const char*>,int> timesCalled;

    FunctionTraceManager(){}
    FunctionTraceManager(FunctionTraceManager const&){}
    ~FunctionTraceManager(){}
    void operator = (FunctionTraceManager const&){}

    public:
        //this method will be the only way to get a FnTraceMgr object, and once statically created, further calls will retrieve the first (and only) FnTraceMgr
        //Object created.
        static FunctionTraceManager& getInstance()
        {
            static FunctionTraceManager fnTraceMgrInstance;
            return fnTraceMgrInstance;
        }
        std::vector<FunctionCallDetails>& getAllFunctionCalls()
        std::map<std::pair<const int,const char*>,int>& getAllTimesCalled()
        {
            if(functionCalls.size() > 0)
            {
                return functionCalls;
            }
            else
            {
                functionCalls.push_back(FunctionCallDetails(-1,"",-1));
                return functionCalls;
            }
        }
        std::map<std::pair<const int,const char*>,int>& getAllTimesCalled(){return timesCalled;}
        std::vector<std::string>& gatherFunctionCalls();
};
class FunctionTrace
{
    public:
        FunctionTrace(const int iLineNumber, const char* iFile);
        ~FunctionTrace();
};

#define LOG_FUNC_CALL FunctionTrace functionTrace(__LINE__,__FILE__);
#endif
```

MathsException.hpp

```
#ifndef MATHS_EXCEPTION_HPP
#define MATHS_EXCEPTION_HPP
#include <exception>
#include "FunctionTrace.hpp"



#include <iostream>
class MathsException : public std::exception
{
    std::string errMsg;
    public:
        MathsException() throw() { LOG_FUNC_CALL };
        MathsException(const std::string iMsg): errMsg(iMsg){ LOG_FUNC_CALL }
        MathsException(const char* iMsg): errMsg(iMsg){ LOG_FUNC_CALL }
        std::string appendFunctionTracing()
        {
            LOG_FUNC_CALL
            std::string oStr = "";
            FunctionTraceManager& fnTraceMgr = FunctionTraceManager::getInstance();

            std::cout << "Why am I not seeing this at all !???";
            std::cout << "Why am I only seeing this once !???  fnTraceMgr.gatherFunctionCalls().size(): " << fnTraceMgr.gatherFunctionCalls().size() << "\n";
            std::vector<std::string>::iterator fnCallsIter = fnTraceMgr.gatherFunctionCalls().begin();
            for(; fnCallsIter != fnTraceMgr.gatherFunctionCalls().end(); ++fnCallsIter)
            {
                oStr += *fnCallsIter;
                oStr += "\n";
            }
            oStr += errMsg;
            return oStr;
        }
        void what()
        {
            LOG_FUNC_CALL
            std::cout << appendFunctionTracing();
        }

        ~MathsException() throw(){LOG_FUNC_CALL}
};

#endif
```

gdb output

```
greg@greg-Aspire-5742:~/Documents/MMath/c++projects/2012_revision/Solver$ gdb Solver
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.3-0ubuntu2) 7.3-2011.08
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb-linaro/>...
Reading symbols from /home/greg/Documents/MMath/c++projects/2012_revision/Solver/Solver...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/greg/Documents/MMath/c++projects/2012_revision/Solver/Solver 
Why am I not seeing this at all !???count: 1
fnDetail: Function at line: -1, in file:  called: -1 times.
count: 2
fnDetail: Function at line: 10, in file: main.cpp called: 1 times.
count: 3
fnDetail: Function at line: 35, in file: MathsException.hpp called: 1 times.
count: 4
fnDetail: Function at line: 18, in file: MathsException.hpp called: 1 times.
Why am I only seeing this once !???  fnTraceMgr.gatherFunctionCalls().size(): 4
count: 5
fnDetail: Function at line: -1, in file:  called: -1 times.
count: 6
fnDetail: Function at line: 10, in file: main.cpp called: 1 times.
count: 7
fnDetail: Function at line: 35, in file: MathsException.hpp called: 1 times.
count: 8
fnDetail: Function at line: 18, in file: MathsException.hpp called: 1 times.
count: 9
fnDetail: Function at line: -1, in file:  called: -1 times.
count: 10
fnDetail: Function at line: 10, in file: main.cpp called: 1 times.
count: 11
fnDetail: Function at line: 35, in file: MathsException.hpp called: 1 times.
count: 12
fnDetail: Function at line: 18, in file: MathsException.hpp called: 1 times.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb7f6e478 in std::string::append(std::string const&) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
(gdb) info locals
No symbol table info available.
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb7f6e478 in std::string::append(std::string const&) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x0804b564 in operator+= (__str=..., this=0xbffff138) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:925
#2  MathsException::appendFunctionTracing (this=0x80530d8) at MathsException.hpp:27
#3  0x0804989b in what (this=0x80530d8) at MathsException.hpp:36
#4  main (argc=Cannot access memory at address 0x1
) at main.cpp:19
(gdb) info locals
No symbol table info available.
(gdb) up
#1  0x0804b564 in operator+= (__str=..., this=0xbffff138) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:925
925       { return this->append(__str); }
(gdb) info locals
No locals.
(gdb) up
#2  MathsException::appendFunctionTracing (this=0x80530d8) at MathsException.hpp:27
27              oStr += *fnCallsIter;
(gdb) info locals
functionTrace = {<No data fields>}
oStr = {static npos = <optimized out>, _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_p = 0x80523ac ""}}
fnCallsIter = {_M_current = 0x8053310}
(gdb) up
#3  0x0804989b in what (this=0x80530d8) at MathsException.hpp:36
36          std::cout << appendFunctionTracing();
(gdb) info locals
functionTrace = {<No data fields>}
(gdb) up
#4  main (argc=Cannot access memory at address 0x1
) at main.cpp:19
19      iException.what();
(gdb) info locals
iException = @0x80530d8
functionTrace = {<No data fields>}
(gdb) up
Initial frame selected; you cannot go up.
```

**Edits:** added in the bottom few lines of FunctionTrace.hpp I missed

Const'd all the parameters I can to see if the compiler will help me - still no use

Added some ifs before I return possibly empty objects - I still get the same seg fault but the gdb output is different (still wierd though)

**progress:**
changing  calls like

```
std::vector<FunctionCallDetails>::iterator fnCallsIter =  fnTraceMgr.getAllFunctionCalls().begin();
```

to

```
std::vector<FunctionCallDetails> fnCalls =  fnTraceMgr.getAllFunctionCalls();
std::vector<FunctionCallDetails>::iterator fnCallsIter =  fnCalls.begin();
```

(and updating the for loop) has removed the seg fault; Somehow my iterator has been pointing to somewhere silly

and undoing that last step I don't get a seg fault (where previously I did)

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a reference to a local variable in `FunctionTraceManager::gatherFunctionCalls`.

A reference is much like a pointer, and returning a reference basically returns the address of the variable. However as local variables in functions are going out of scope when the function returns, those variables can't be referenced (via pointers or references). This is *undefined behaviour*, and may work sometimes but often weird things will happen, like the program crashing.

Comment: Thanks for that, and good point about scoping (I'm aware of it but this one passed me by)...am I correct in saying my methodology is wrong, as opposed to the ampersand being there? (and removing it, recompiling, and re-running leaves what seems to be precisely the same error also...suggesting problems elsewhere too)